# T test difference in means: many subsets in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'd like to conduct a t-test for the difference in means BETWEEN all factor levels in a more efficient way than individual t-tests (actual data has 50 factor levels)).

example data:

```
dat <- cbind(rnorm(10), c("x","x","x","y","y","y","z","z","a","a"))
```

I'd like to output t-stat for all iterations of difference in means (x-y, y-z, z-x, a-x, a-y, a-z)

I've see how to do this using apply for a test of difference from 0, but can't connect how to leverage this approach to do a difference in means. Could hack it with a for loop, but there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: Can you show your for loop please?

Comment: Have you looked at the `TukeyHSD` function? When you perform comparisons between many levels of factors, efficiency isn't the only concern: multiple testing is a much bigger issue, and Tukey HSD (honest significant differences) is the right way to handle it.